# Two imgs of variable size in a row, their middle centered on screen, with horizontal scrolling if too large

Tags: html, css

I basically want to display 2 images next to each other, aligned in a way that they touch in the center of the screen (independent of the image size). I was able to get it done with fixed positioning, but in this case, there will be no scrolling if the images are too large for "their" respective side of the screen.

HTML:

```
<div class="left">
    <img src="xyz.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <img src="abc.jpg"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left {
   position: fixed;
   right: calc(50% + 10px); 
   width: auto;
}
.right {
   position: fixed;
   left: calc(50% + 10px); 
   width: auto;
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/z9926e15/)

Any idea how I can get the same behavior, but with horizontal scrolling? I believe it cannot be done with position: fixed. Is there another way?
Thanks1

Answer (score 0):

You can use float and half of the width(50%). The scroll with appear automatically since the body's default value for overflow is auto(scroll).

Try this and see if it is what you want.

```
<div class="left">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/afd65O1.png" />
</div>
<div class="right">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WTuWgFvl.jpg" />
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.left,
.right {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpbg2zxe/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this does not have the desired effect. in your updated fiddle. Images are aligned left and right respectively, and not centered. And they overlap, if the screen size is too small.

Comment: Hi Adrian, thanks for your help. This solution doesnt seem to work for me  either, images are aligned left, I want the touching point to be the center of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
.left {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.right {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: works somewhat, but each img has its own scrollbar, i would like to have a singe one :)